# Wifi issue with Dell XPS 15

Tags: 18.04, wireless

I am finding that my work laptop works 100% fine on the office wireless, but when I get it to my own laptop, the wifi connects, but the browser doesn't load any pages (or if it does, they are very slow to load).

At the moment I cannot even ping google, so in trying to 'fix' this issue, I may have made it worse.

I do a lot of development in my job with docker, so wonder whether all the 'bridge' networks could be causing an issue.

Any suggestions on steps to resolve this would be great.  As at the moment, I am blaming my router, and trying to decide whether to fork out the money for a new one.

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: Docker bridge adapters can affect things, yes. If possible I would suggest removing the bridge adapters you've set up and see if it solves your issue. I don't have enough experience with it to debug unfortunately, but I experienced the same symptoms as you and managed to solve by removing the adapters, and setting them up again with better understanding later, not affecting my wifi.

Comment: Thanks, I have a few things to try based on your comment.  Today I did a bulk prune of the networks, and it now appears to connect (which is great).  So next time I will try to be a little more precise to see if I can narrow down the cause.  A friend at work has suggested looking at resolv.conf too

Comment: You're at least lucky you understood the connection quickly. I used an entire working day and an hour of support staff's time before figuring out the bridge adapter was the culprit o.0 Good luck :)